# Node.js Axios no error message program stops running

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, npm, error-handling, axios

This code is making requests to the same endpoint and iterating over a number.

The code will randomly (sometimes the first time, sometimes not until 50+, completely random)

just stop working!... No error message or anything, it just stops.

It logs the line just before the instance.get method and then doesn't do anything after that.
Logs a blank line and quits.

**The last few lines it logs are:**

```
(...axios response)
after request... 12
before request... 13
(blank line...)
```

**Example of the code:**

```
/* Axios Ebay Instance */
const UserAgent = require('user-agents');
const agent = new UserAgent().toString();
const ebay = require('axios').default.create({
    baseURL: `https://www.ebay.com/`,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': agent
    }
});

(async () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        console.log('before request...', i);
        try{
        const r = await ebay.get(
            `/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Fontaine+Red+playing+cards&_sacat=0&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&_pgn=${i}`);
            console.log(r);
        }catch(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        console.log('after request...', i);
    } 
})();
```

Comment: Yep, I had the same problem a while back. It turns out, this is an old and known Axios bug that was never fixed, and won't be anytime soon. My solution? Getting rid of Axios and switching to node-fetch.

Comment: How annoying. I tried for a couple hours to get it sorted out to no avail... Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Do you have any more info? Link to bug?